# PHP XSL Issue with Data Cataloguing Application

Tags: php, xslt

I see the following error on a web page when trying to run a PHP based data cataloguing application:

> Fatal error: XSL extension was not loaded. Please check the php configurations and enable the extension.
>
> Error source: xslTransform

Has anyone seen this before?
What may be the cause of this?

Comment: For XSLT, you need to enable `php_xsl` in the ini file. Then be sure to restart server.

Comment: I did that and it didn't make a difference. Any other thoughts or advice? Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what you specifically did.